# Specifying element type for DXF creation using ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

I am trying to create a DXF from a Polygon Shapefile using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF parcels.dxf parcels.shp
```

The problem is that the polygons are written as hatch elements.

How do I specify that ogr2ogr should create LWPOLYLINE elements (Or any other [supported type](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_dxf.html))?

I have tried this from command line and from QGIS 'save as' option with the same result.  I don't remember this being an issue in the past, but seems like it started with GDAL version 1.10.x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `-nlt` option to force type of object. You can test `-nlt MULTILINESTRING` or `-nlt LINESTRING` with your command. I think it can work.

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF parcels.dxf parcels.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING
```

In the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) your can read:

> -nlt type: Define the geometry type for the created layer. One of NONE, GEOMETRY, POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,
>   MULTIPOINT, MULTIPOLYGON or MULTILINESTRING. Add "25D" to the name to
>   get 2.5D versions. Starting with GDAL 1.10, PROMOTE_TO_MULTI can be
>   used to automatically promote layers that mix polygon or multipolygons
>   to multipolygons, and layers that mix linestrings or multilinestrings
>   to multilinestrings. Can be usefull when converting shapefiles to
>   PostGIS (and other target drivers) that implements strict checks for
>   geometry type.

Comment: Unbelievable.  I read and reread the documentation and still missed it.  And that's after doing the same thing with the -zfield option.