# Existing C++ libraries that convert ESRI shapefile to DXF/DWG

Tags: shapefile, software-recommendations, c++, dxf, dwg

Is there any C++ library that can convert ESRI Shapefile to DXF/DWG file?

I seek a link/or sample on how this can be done with the said C++ library.

I'm aware that one can do this with ArcGIS Desktop application itself, but this is not what I want. I want to write code that can do this with my own UI.

Comment: Why is it being put on hold? I thought this is perfectly answerable? There is at least [one answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/304510/1261) (right or wrong is an entirely different issue) that addresses this well within the scope

Comment: I would have voted to close this question as primarily *opinion-based*. It is broad, but it encourages list-building, which isn't compatible with the "Focused question/Best answer" model used here.

Comment: Since you have GDAL provided as an answer you could focus your question on that. If it does not meet your requirements just ask another focused question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GDAL](https://gdal.org/) supports open [ESRI Shapefile](https://gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html) and save it as [DXF](https://gdal.org/drv_dxf.html).
The C++ API intro is here: https://gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html

Comment: Do you have the relevant documentation section that shows how to achieve this in GDAL?

Comment: All documentation are available at https://www.gdal.org. The case with converting one format to another are described at tutorial https://gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html. Also you can look at [ogr2ogr](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) command line utility and it [sources](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/apps/ogr2ogr_bin.cpp).

Comment: You mean doing something like using [ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80812/1261) command line utility conversion?

Comment: You can try command line utility and if it suits you - you can see sources how file format conversion (for example between ESRI Shape to DXF) done. And use this code in you application/library.

Comment: You mean, I would have to look into the source code on how the conversion is done?

Comment: I recommend to start from [tutorial](https://gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html), as it more simple. If it not suits you or you want **quick prototyping**, try command line utility (get it from OSGeo4W or NextGIS Installer) and then go deeper into the sources of ogr2ogr.